# How to safely remove "extra" python on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, python

so I've some extra python version installed and I was wondering if there was a safe way to keep just python2.7 and python3.8 for cleanliness without any damage to the system.

[image]

For instance, depending on the version, an `apt-get remove` lists me a lot of extras that I don't think should be actually removed. I've installed all versions but python3.8 (done building source files) via package manager.

removing python3.6

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apparmor apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl apturl-common firefox foomatic-db-compressed-ppds gdm3 gedit gedit-common gir1.2-ibus-1.0
  gnome-control-center gnome-menus gnome-online-accounts gnome-shell gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap gnome-terminal hplip hplip-data ibus
  ibus-table language-selector-common language-selector-gnome lsb-release nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal nautilus-share nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings openprinting-ppds orca printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-m2300w printer-driver-postscript-hp
  printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr python3 python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-asn1crypto
  python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-certifi python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet python3-crypto python3-cryptography python3-cups
  python3-cupshelpers python3-dateutil python3-dbus python3-debconf python3-debian python3-defer python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-gi
  python3-gi-cairo python3-httplib2 python3-idna python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-launchpadlib python3-lazr.restfulclient
  python3-lazr.uri python3-louis python3-macaroonbakery python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-nacl python3-oauth python3-olefile python3-pexpect
  python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report python3-protobuf python3-ptyprocess python3-pyatspi python3-pymacaroons python3-renderpm
  python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket python3-rfc3339 python3-secretstorage python3-simplejson
  python3-six python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-systemd python3-tz python3-update-manager python3-urllib3 python3-wadllib
  python3-xdg python3-xkit python3-yaml python3-zope.interface python3.6 rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins
  screen-resolution-extra snapd software-properties-common software-properties-gtk system-config-printer system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-udev totem-plugins ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-session ubuntu-software ubuntu-system-service unattended-upgrades update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common
  usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk xorg xserver-xorg
```

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python python-all python-all-dev python-asn1crypto python-cffi-backend python-crypto python-cryptography python-dbus python-dev python-enum34
  python-gi python-idna python-ipaddress python-keyring python-keyrings.alt python-pip python-pkg-resources python-secretstorage python-setuptools
  python-six python-wheel python-xdg python2.7 python2.7-dev
```

I've already removed two of them time ago and was pretty harmful for the system since I had to reinstall many core features along the way back. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Many Ubuntu system programs rely on the default python (3.6.7) so removing it will mean you'll lose access to those parts of the system, ie. there will be consequences.

Comment: So, leaving python3.6 and python2.7 is mandatory but 3.8 for instance isn't?

Comment: The default python/python2/python3 (2.7 if using a release that has python meaning python2 or 3.x if using later releases) should not be touched as Ubuntu tools expect that version to be default and may stop working if it's changed. Changing it requires some careful work. but I'll provide https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3 to view which versions are default.  (the package `python` doesn't exist for focal, it was dropped from main in 19.04, renamed and then renamed in *focal*); *drop the 3 from the url to see python for all releases*